# Number of triangles in a random graph.

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, probabilistic-method

Let G be the random graph $G\left(n,\frac{\log(n)}n\right)$, i.e. the graph on $n$ vertices with each edge independently having probability $\frac{\log(n)}n$ of being in the graph.

I wrote a program to find the number of triangles in this graph, call it $X$. Intuitively and from my results it seems that $E_n[X]$ tends to 0 as $n\rightarrow \infty$. I am wondering how I might go about proving this. For $G(n,c/n)$ I know that $E_n[X]=\frac{c^3}{6}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, not sure if this could be relevant.

Comment: We have $\mathsf EX_n = \binom n3 \cdot \frac{\ln(n)^3}{n^3}$ which converges to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood a part of my notes a great deal and than was doing something idiotic in my simulation to compound that misunderstanding. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Just to confirm I understand correctly, for G(n, p), $E_n[X]=\binom{n}{3}p^3$, right?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$